# RippleButton class is working in one Python script but not while working with screens

Tags: python, kivy

While I run this script rippleexample2.py with rippleexample2.kv, the buttons should have ripple effects upon pressing, but it doesn't work.

I know the `RippleButton` class is working fine in ctmbtn.py, when a button is pressed here, there is ripple effect. I don't know what is wrong here. Perhaps binding function?

rippleexample2.py

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.touchripple import TouchRippleBehavior
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.properties import (StringProperty, NumericProperty, ObjectProperty, ListProperty, DictProperty, BooleanProperty)

class RippleButton(TouchRippleBehavior, Button):

    isRippled = BooleanProperty(False)

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(RippleButton, self).__init__(**kwargs)

    def on_touch_down(self, touch):
            collide_point = self.collide_point(touch.x, touch.y)
        if collide_point and not self.isRippled:
            self.isRippled = True
            self.ripple_show(touch)
        return super(RippleButton, self).on_touch_down(touch)

    def on_touch_up(self, touch):
        collide_point = self.collide_point(touch.x, touch.y)
        if collide_point and self.isRippled:
            self.isRippled = False
            self.ripple_fade()
        return super(RippleButton, self).on_touch_up(touch)


class Login(Screen):
    pass

class MainScreen(Screen):
    pass

class ScreenManager(ScreenManager):
    pass

Login = Builder.load_file("rippleexample2.kv")

class SimpleKivy4(App):
    def build(self):
        return Login

if __name__ == "__main__":
    SimpleKivy4().run()
```

rippleexample2.kv

```
ScreenManager:
    Login:
    MainScreen:

<Login>:
    name:"login"
    RippleButton:
        text:'Login'
        font_size: 24
        size_hint: (.4,.25)
        on_release: app.root.current = "main"

<MainScreen>:
    name: "main"
    Button:
        text: 'back'
        on_release: app.root.current = "login"
```

ctmbtn.py

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.properties import (StringProperty, NumericProperty, ObjectProperty,
ListProperty, DictProperty, BooleanProperty)
from kivy.uix.touchripple import TouchRippleBehavior

class RippleButton(TouchRippleBehavior, Button):
    isRippled = BooleanProperty(False)

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(RippleButton, self).__init__(**kwargs)

    def on_touch_down(self, touch):
        collide_point = self.collide_point(touch.x, touch.y)
        if collide_point and not self.isRippled:
            self.isRippled = True
            self.ripple_show(touch)
        return super(RippleButton, self).on_touch_down(touch)

    def on_touch_up(self, touch):
        collide_point = self.collide_point(touch.x, touch.y)
        if collide_point and self.isRippled:
            self.isRippled = False
            self.ripple_fade()
        return super(RippleButton, self).on_touch_up(touch)


class RootWidget(BoxLayout):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(RootWidget, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.add_widget(RippleButton(text='btn 1'))
        cb = CustomBtn()
        cb.bind(pressed=self.btn_pressed)
        self.add_widget(cb)
        self.add_widget(RippleButton(text='btn 2'))

    def btn_pressed(self, instance, pos):
        print ('pos: printed from root widget: {pos}'.format(pos=pos))

class CustomBtn(Widget):
    pressed = ListProperty([0, 0])

    def on_touch_down(self, touch):
        if self.collide_point(*touch.pos):
            self.pressed = touch.pos
            # we consumed the touch. return False here to propagate
            # the touch further to the children.
            return True
        return super(CustomBtn, self).on_touch_down(touch)

    def on_pressed(self, instance, pos):
        print ('pressed at {pos}'.format(pos=pos))

class TestApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return RootWidget()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    TestApp().run()
```

Comment: I think this is a bug in Kivy. I did a similar example, but even simpler, using just a `RelativeLayout` and your `RippleButton`. It worked fine using just Python, but fails when using kv. You might want to create an issue at `https://github.com/kivy/kivy`

Answer (score 0):

The Touch Ripple code is still experimental, and it is not visible when using it in kv language for Button widget.

Actually, the Button touch ripple animation on interaction works when using kv language. It is just not visible because the `background_color` (r, g, b, a) of Button widget defaults to [1, 1, 1, 1] or grey color with no transparency. Whereby 'a' (alpha compositing or transparency) is 1 i.e. not transparent.

The ripple_color defaults to [1., 1., 1., .5] or grey color with half transparency.

## Solution

The temporary work around is to change the alpha compositing or transparency of Button widget to 0.5.

Please refer to my example for [Kivy RippleButton](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54147577/how-to-use-touchripple-py-with-kivy-lang/54660140#54660140)